# q file not being executed in KDB

Tags: kdb

I have downloaded KDB+ from http://code.kx.com/q/tutorials/install/#microsoft-windows and unzipped it to my C: drive.

When I browse into the q\w32 directory and try to run any file I always get the file name printed out with an apostrophe in front of it.

e.g.

```
cd C:\q\w32>
C:\q\w32>q
q)q trade.q          (I have copied the example trade.q into the w32 folder)
'trade.q
```

Why does this not run the file??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use either `\l` or `system "l trade.q"` to load a file into your q workspace.

E.g.

[Loading trade.q for q in Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXhQc.png)

Also the apostrophe `'` means error, i.e. the q process can't interpret 'trade.q'

Hope this help!

Answer (score 2):

`q trade.q` is what you would run from the command line to start a q process and load in trade.q during initialisation.

If your q process is already running you will have to do as David says, and use `\l` or `load`.